# How to disable (gray out) page action for Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want the Chrome extension icon to be disabled (grayed out) on all pages except for pages on docs.google.com. This is my code in background.js.

```
'use strict';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { urlContains: 'docs.google' },
      })
      ],
          actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});
```

From the documentation for [pageActions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show) this should result in my extension icon being gray on all pages except for ones that have docs.google in the URL. But the icon is active (NOT grayed out) on all pages. Tapping it on non docs.google pages results in it not doing anything, but I want it to be grayed out in the first place.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1127067) and so far it's unclear if it's even fixable.

Meanwhile, you can maintain the icon yourself:

1. make a grayscale version of the icon(s) in any image editor and save them separately.
2. specify the gray icon in manifest.json:

   - ManifestV2:

     ```js
     "page_action": {
       "default_icon": { "16": "icons/16-gray.png", "32": "icons/32-gray.png" }
     }
     ```
   - ManifestV3 uses `action` instead of `page_action`

     ```js
     "action": {
       "default_icon": { "16": "icons/16-gray.png", "32": "icons/32-gray.png" }
     }
     ```
3. set the normal icon using [SetIcon](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-SetIcon) action:

   ```js
   chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(async () => {
     chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
       conditions: [
         new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
           pageUrl: { hostPrefix: 'docs.google.' },
         }),
       ],
       actions: [
         new chrome.declarativeContent.SetIcon({
           imageData: {
             16: await loadImageData('icons/16.png'),
             32: await loadImageData('icons/32.png'),
           },
         }),
         chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction
           ? new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()
           : new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction(),
       ],
     }]);
   });

   // SVG icons aren't supported yet
   async function loadImageData(url) {
     const img = await createImageBitmap(await (await fetch(url)).blob());
     const {width: w, height: h} = img;
     const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(w, h);
     const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
     return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
   }
   ```

Comment: I read the bug description and the comments: When will this bug likely be resolved?

Comment: for me it crashed on "await" - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Was it because of the manifest v2?

Comment: after calling "chrome.action.setIcon(someAnotherIcon)" in "chrome.action.onClicked" it stops working (icon not chaged anymore, someAnotherIcon showed)  why can that be? -.-

Comment: Sounds like a bug or an inherent limitation of the API.

Comment: For Edge, the colored icon is greyed out iff there is no content.js.  But add that and it is coloured even when hidden.  Wasted quite a bit of time on this.

Comment: Tested with `manifest v3`, and works perfectly!

Comment: @velkoon, I've just verified the code works correctly in an MV3 extension (there's also robe007's comment) so you can debug it yourself or ask a new question with a full [MCVE](/help/mcve) because comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: To Googlers: Note you must declare `"permissions": ["declarativeContent"]` in your `manifest.json`. (And for that matter, remember to declare in your `manifest.json` whatever permissions are listed at the top of the respective official doc, like on this one: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeContent/ )

Answer (score 2):

Chrome documents this behavior in their docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#emulating-pageactions-with-declarativecontent. The following describes how to achieve it in manifest v3.

```js
// background.js

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  // disable the action by default
  chrome.action.disable();

  // remove existing rules so only ours are applied
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    // add a custom rule
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // define the rule's conditions
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostSuffix: "reddit.com" },
          }),
        ],
        // show the action when conditions are met
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()],
      },
    ]);
  });
});
```

This will require the `declarativeContent` permission in `manifest.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "permissions": ["declarativeContent"]
  ...
}
```

Comment: This does not gray out the icon, it just disables the action from being fired when clicked.

Comment: @Jeph it will gray it out for sites that do not match the pattern you define in manifest.json. If you're not seeing it work, double check the match pattern and make sure you're visiting a site that it should not match. This very approach is used for this extension and it grays out fine: https://github.com/dan-lovelace/reddit-theme-studio/blob/main/assets/manifest-v3.json

Answer (score 1):

If you use manifest version 2, just need to declare the colored icon in page_action, rather than the gray one.

```
// manifest.json
 "manifest_version": 2
 "page_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon-color.png"
 },
```

And then the icon will be gray in the URL out of permissions and matches.
You can see the description at [pageAction/#manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageAction/#manifest).

But in manifest v3, it seems the configures above no works longer.