# Make Google Chrome Extension disabled by default

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to make my Google Chrome Extension disabled by default and then enable it based on the content flow , how could I achieve it ?

Here is the API to make the extension disabled , I need that by default .
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-disable

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504), it shows how to do it via page_action which is basically the same thing as browser_action but more suited for your use case. Depending on what "content flow" is there could be different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your background page (as configured in `manifest.json` e.g.):

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/background.js"
    ]
}
```

You can do the following to disable the extension each time a tab is opened::

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(() => {
    chrome.browserAction.disable();
});
```

Then later, based on flow call `chrome.browserAction.enable();`

Comment: I got error: 
> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'disable')...

Comment: @Marcin - "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'disable')" - This error means that whatever is to the left of `.disable()` is undefined. In this case, that's `chrome.action`. So you either haven't defined an action in manifest.json, or you're trying to call `chrome.action.disable()` in a content script. See [Content scripts > Understand content script capabilities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#capabilities)