# Make custom/own Google Chrome Extension disabled by default

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension is trying to find a specific HTML element on the page. When extension finds this HTML element, extension should be turned on, i.e. it should enable opening the popup after clicking on the extension icon. That's why I would like the extension to be disabled by default, and only when the content.js script finds the specific HTML element it should launch/enable the extension.

I found the `chrome.action.disable()` method, but I don't know if it's a good solution and where I should call it.

PS.
Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64521476 does not work for me.

Comment: [chrome.action > Emulating pageActions with declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#emulating-pageactions-with-declarativecontent)