# weird Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently learning to develop a google chrome extension. I'm trying to get a button to list all of the `span` elements in the console for now. However, I can't seem to set the function of the button and keep getting a weird `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` error.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Simple Greeting Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <button id="main-switch">Update prices:</button>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>


</html>
```

main.js:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("This is working!");

    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
            chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
                conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'steamcommunity.com' },
                })],
                actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
            }]);
        });
    });

    function update_prices() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        console.log("Elements:", elements);
    }
    document.getElementById('main-switch').onclick = update_prices;
};
```

manifest.json:

```json
{
    "name": "Steam price helper",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Helps with prices on the Steam community market",
    "incognito": "split",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "declarativeContent"
    ],

    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "256": "download.png"
        }
    },

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I've looked at other questions that have the same problem, but none of those solutions seem to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't show manifest.json which is one of the most important things in an extension so I can only guess you're loading the same script main.js as a background script which is totally wrong (you need two separate scripts because the background script is already running in its own hidden background page).

Comment: @wOxxOm updated with manifest

Comment: So my guess was right.

Comment: Why are you using `defer` when the script tag is already at the end of the body?

Comment: @wOxxOm could you please explain a bit further? don't get it fully from your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `background` in manifest.json, it creates a background page where the specified scripts run. It's a hidden separate page. You can debug it its own [separate devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/accessing-console-and-devtools-of-extensions-background-js).

The `browser_action` or `page_action` popup is also a separate page. It's not related to the background script/page. It also has its own separate devtools which you can access by right-clicking inside the popup and choosing "Inspect".

You can use both devtools to debug the problem: set breakpoints, reload the page via Ctrl-R or F5 key, step through the code and actually see what happens so there's no need to guess.

**Currently you run the same main.js in two pages.** So, one instance of main.js runs in the background script's page where DOM is empty and naturally it doesn't find any elements.

**The solution is to split it into two scripts.** One script will be the background script that registers API stuff. Another script will run in the popup and deal with UI stuff.

1. In manifest.json declare `"background": {"scripts": ["bg.js", "persistent":false]}`
2. Make bg.js:

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
     chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(() => {
       chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
         conditions: [
           new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
             pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'steamcommunity.com'},
           }),
         ],
         actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()],
       }]);
     });
   });
   ```
3. Make popup.js:

   ```js
   document.getElementById('main-switch').onclick = function () {
     var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
     console.log('Elements:', elements);
   };
   ```
4. Load it in your html: `<script src=popup.js></script>`

   No need for `defer` or `async` attributes. No need for `window.load` either: the script
   already runs when DOM is ready as it's the last thing in HTML.

**Notes:**

- To view the console output, use the correct devtools as explained at the beginning of this answer.
- To gray out the icon on non-matching sites, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504).

Comment: This helped remove the errors. However, I might have not made this clear in the question, my bad: I want to list all of the elements on the page of where the popup is active, not of the popup itself - so all of the `span`s on the steam page in my example, and currently this looks for the elements on the popup page

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)