# How to send a message from popup.js to background.js with a page action so it executes a content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I made my first browser extension. The first version works decently, but can be improved, so I'm refactoring.... And in this new version, I'm using a `page_action` because it's important that this extension only works on one url pattern: `*://*.website.com/abc*`. The popup shows up fine on only this page, and won't show on others - exactly as I want it, but I can't get the `popup.js` to send a message to my `background.js` so it runs a [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#programmatic) on the DOM of the current browser url via `content_script.js`.

For some reason, it also shows the icon as colored on every page *(which I want grey)*, and I was under the impression that the `ShowPageAction()` method could auto grey out anything that didn't meet the conditions for it. Here's my code for it all.

**manifest.js**

```
{
  "name": ".........",
  "description" : "...........",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/a.png",
    "32": "images/b.png",
    "48": "images/c.png",
    "128": "images/d.png"
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/a.png",
      "32": "images/b.png",
      "48": "images/c.png",
      "128": "images/d.png"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage", "webNavigation", "*://*.website.com/abc*"],
}
```

**background.js**

The 2nd listener below isn't receiving the message.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.local.set({some_val: 0});
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher(
        {pageUrl: {urlContains: '.website.com/abc'},}
      )],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.some_msg == 'some_msg'){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'content_script.js'});
  }
});
```

**popup.js**

For the following, I've tried both `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()`, and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`, but neither are working... `my_function` is also bound to an event handler on the popup, and works fine, it's just doesn't `sendMessage()`.

```
function my_function(){
    ....
    // chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    //   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {some_msg : 'some_msg'})
    // })
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({some_msg : 'some_msg'});
    ....
};
```

**content_script.js**

```
var e = document.getElementById('abcde');
// do stuff with the browser DOM ---- NOT the popup DOM.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use devtools debugger because the code is fine and if you set a breakpoint in devtools for the background script inside the listener you should see it triggering. Regarding the icon, see [How to disable (gray out) page action for Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504). BTW in this simplified example there's no need for onMessage in the background script because you can do executeScript in the popup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed it by adding `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` in my `popup.js` like you said, and removed the message sending. Although, how would I do what you're saying for the debugging?? I think you meant use the chrome dev tools by right click + Inspect >> Sources >> popup.js >> set click event breakpoint, and step through line by line. I did that, saw nothing useful in the call stack or scope. And hovering over `sendMessage()` also showed no properties that would indicate which file the message was being sent to. `console.log()` wasn't working either.