# Chrome extension show page action example manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to reproduce [this example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/mv2-archive/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url) with the **manifest v3**. But my action is always active - I expext it to be disabled on all pages without 'g' in a URL.

Thanks in advance!

manifest.json

```
{
   "name":"Example",
   "description":"description",
   "version":"0.1",
   "manifest_version":3,
   "background":{
      "service_worker":"background.js"
   },
   "permissions":[
      "declarativeContent"
   ],
   "action":{
      "default_icon":{
         "16":"/images/get_started16.png",
         "32":"/images/get_started32.png",
         "48":"/images/get_started48.png",
         "128":"/images/get_started128.png"
      },
      "default_title":"press here to open"
   },
   "icons":{
      "16":"/images/get_started16.png",
      "32":"/images/get_started32.png",
      "48":"/images/get_started48.png",
      "128":"/images/get_started128.png"
   }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains a 'g' ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'g' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ], function callback(details) {
      console.log("chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules callback");
      console.log(details);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: See [How to disable (gray out) page action for Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504)

Comment: @wOxxOm that link refers to manifest v2, the question asks for manifest v3.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The API almost didn't change, just a couple of things were renamed.

Comment: For further info see: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/  - Emulating pageActions with declarativeContent this specifically references manifest V3.

Comment: As wOxxOm mentioned in his comment: [this answer helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) mentioned
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504) helped.