# Manifest v3 pageAction.show()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i'm in the painful process of migrating my extension from manifest v2 to v3, and among the many issues i have to solve actually i can't find a solution to this one.

Basically in my manifest v2 had a background page with the following line of code:

```js
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
```

But now in manifest v3 pageAction and browserAction are no longer available, and the *.show()* method in the new *.action* object is not available. When i try to load the extension i get the following error:

```
 in event handler: TypeError: chrome.action.show is not a function
    at chrome-extension://ilffkamoglijakcakajaackcckakgddi/src/background.js:31:25
background.js:26
```

I tried to look around in the v3 docuentation, but i failed to find a solution to my problem, how am i supposed to replace the *.show()* method?

Comment: You'll have to set a different icon I guess. See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475504).

Comment: not sure why? if my plan is to refresh a page why i should set a different icon?

Comment: Because there's no page action anymore in MV3, you can only change the icon itself.

Comment: yeah i know that the pageAction is removed from manifest v3, but i was hopign there was a better candidate... i was looking at few examples (not even sure if they will solve my issue) but basically 2 lines of code now must be replaced with something like 15/20 lines of code (and is not the first time with this migration that it happens... very frustrating!)

Answer (score 0):

If what you try to achieve is to have the extension button enabled only when a relevant page is open in the current tab, you can use the [Declarative Content technique](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#emulate-pageactions-with-declarativecontent) in your Service Worker:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.action.disable();

  // Clear all rules to ensure only our expected rules are set
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
  let mainRule = {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: {hostSuffix: '.someDomain.com', pathPrefix: '/somePrefix/'},
      })
    ],
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()],
  };

  // Finally, apply our new array of rules
  let rules = [mainRule];
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules(rules);
  });
});
```

For this to work, you also need to mention the "declarativeContent" permission in your manifest.json.